# Getting a blank value or - + number $value to show in Regex

Tags: regex, vb.net

```
MsgType=GetMarketAuction&Symbol=XLF&AuctionPrice=24.50&AuctionSize=57138&AuctionImbalance=0&AuctionImbalanceMkt=0&AuctionIndNetChange=&ClosingPrice=24.54&BidPrice=24.36&AskPrice=24.37&EC=0&ES=&AuctionImbalanceStatus=&AuctionMktImbalanceStatus=&Delta=
```

I am trying to pull all the data needed out of this regex line above. Using VB.net I have the first 5 things but am stuck once there is a -/+ $ number needed that sometimes displays as no character.

This works so far.

```
Dim r As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("Symbol=(?<1>.\w+)\&AuctionPrice=(?<2>.\d.\d+)\&AuctionSize=(?<3>.\d+)\&AuctionImbalance=(?<4>.a*)\&AuctionImbalanceMkt=(?<5>.a*)")
```

AuctionIndNetChange=(I am looking for something here to pull the value from)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
Symbol=(?<1>[^&]*)&AuctionPrice=(?<2>[^&]*)&AuctionSize=(?<3>[^&]*)&AuctionImbalance=(?<4>[^&]*)&AuctionImbalanceMkt=(?<5>[^&]*)&AuctionIndNetChange=(?<6>[^&]*)
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Symbol%3d(%3f%3c1%3e%5b%5e%26%5d*)%26AuctionPrice%3d(%3f%3c2%3e%5b%5e%26%5d*)%26AuctionSize%3d(%3f%3c3%3e%5b%5e%26%5d*)%26AuctionImbalance%3d(%3f%3c4%3e%5b%5e%26%5d*)%26AuctionImbalanceMkt%3d(%3f%3c5%3e%5b%5e%26%5d*)%26AuctionIndNetChange%3d(%3f%3c6%3e%5b%5e%26%5d*)&i=MsgType%3dGetMarketAuction%26Symbol%3dXLF%26AuctionPrice%3d24.50%26AuctionSize%3d57138%26AuctionImbalance%3d0%26AuctionImbalanceMkt%3d0%26AuctionIndNetChange%3d%26ClosingPrice%3d24.54%26BidPrice%3d24.36%26AskPrice%3d24.37%26EC%3d0%26ES%3d%26AuctionImbalanceStatus%3d%26AuctionMktImbalanceStatus%3d%26Delta%3d%0d%0aMsgType%3dGetMarketAuction%26Symbol%3dXLF%26AuctionPrice%3d24.50%26AuctionSize%3d57138%26AuctionImbalance%3d0%26AuctionImbalanceMkt%3d0%26AuctionIndNetChange%3d56%26ClosingPrice%3d24.54%26BidPrice%3d24.36%26AskPrice%3d24.37%26EC%3d0%26ES%3d%26AuctionImbalanceStatus%3d%26AuctionMktImbalanceStatus%3d%26Delta%3d)

Note that you do not have to use numbers in the names of capture groups, you can remove all `?<n>` and you will get the same result.

Also, I replaced all your subpatterns in the capturing groups with `[^&]*` that means *0 or more characters other then `&`*, since all of them are inside the query string.

**HOWEVER**, you can use a non-regex way with [`System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) (do not forget to add a reference to `System.Web`!):

```
Dim querystr As String = "MsgType=GetMarketAuction&Symbol=XLF&AuctionPrice=24.50&AuctionSize=57138&AuctionImbalance=0&AuctionImbalanceMkt=0&AuctionIndNetChange=&ClosingPrice=24.54&BidPrice=24.36&AskPrice=24.37&EC=0&ES=&AuctionImbalanceStatus=&AuctionMktImbalanceStatus=&Delta="
        Dim qscoll As System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystr)
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("AuctionSize: {0}, Symbol: {1}, AuctionPrice: {2}, AuctionSize: {3}, AuctionImbalance: {4}, AuctionImbalanceMkt: {5}, AuctionIndNetChange: {6}",
        qscoll("AuctionSize"), _
        qscoll("Symbol"), _
        qscoll("AuctionPrice"), _
        qscoll("AuctionSize"), _
        qscoll("AuctionImbalance"), _
        qscoll("AuctionImbalanceMkt"), _
        qscoll("AuctionIndNetChange")))
```

Output:

```
AuctionSize: 57138, Symbol: XLF, AuctionPrice: 24.50, AuctionSize: 57138, AuctionImbalance: 0, AuctionImbalanceMkt: 0, AuctionIndNetChange:
```